# selector error when using ARM assambly to achieve an objective-c Method

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I want to use ARM assembly to achieve an objective-c Method,like this:

```
    NSLog(@"%@",objc_msgSend((id)objc_getClass("NSString"),sel_registerName("stringWithUTF8String:"),"abcdefg"));
```

so I wrote such an assembly program:

```
    .data
    .align 4
    output_str:
        .string    "The answer is right"
    nsstring:
        .string     "NSString" 
    stringWithUTF8String:
        .string     "stringWithUTF8String:"
    .text
    .align 4
    .globl _my_arm_test
    .globl _my_thumb_test
    .globl _my_arm_test2
    .extern _printf
    .extern _objc_getClass
    .extern _objc_msgSend
    .extern _NSLog
    .extern _sel_getUid
    .extern _sel_registerName
    .arm
    .align 4
    _my_arm_test2:
        push {r0,lr}
        sub   sp, #0x28
        ldr  r0,=stringWithUTF8String
        bl   _sel_registerName
        cmp  r0,0
        beq  out
        str   r0, [sp]
        ldr   r1, [sp]
        ldr  r0,  =nsstring
        bl   _objc_getClass
        ldr  r2,=output_str
        bl   _objc_msgSend
        bl   _NSLog
    out:
        add  sp, #0x28
        pop  {r0,pc}
```

the program can run,but I found the following error,which showed that there were something wrong with the selector:

```
    *** NSForwarding: warning: selector (0x3a43b0b0) for message '' does not match selector known to Objective C runtime (0x200be0)-- abort
```

And I am sure that the return of _sel_registerName is right,so were there anything others I ignored????

Comment: FYI; you need to cast calls to `objc_msgSend()` to reflect the return type and argument type(s) of the method being called.  If you don't, the generated code may not be correct.

Comment: @bbum it's pretty clear that this isn't an auto-generated bit of assembly, but rather hand written (note the lack of 'cfa' labels, stack preservation around function calls - which incidentally is the issue with this code, and SIMD registers being suspiciously missing - ARMv7's iOS calling conventions REQUIRE all SIMD registers to be stored to the stack, and the clang never breaks that rule).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That wasn't my point;  the initial bit of C code is wrong.  If that were compiled with the purpose of looking at the assembly to determine ARM implementation patterns, it would likely yield incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

YES,I have solve this problem.The key point is that the objc_getClass method will change the value for r1......however this method only need one parameter and return the  Class object.I will go on explore it.

Comment: ARM calling conventions make registers r0-r3 clobber-able by the receiver. You're only guaranteed r4-r7 to be preserved. Use the stack for keeping values around between function calls.

Comment: If you're interested in ARM for iOS, I'd strongly recommend you take a look at the following reading materials: 
[iOS ABI Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009020-SW1), [ARM ABI Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html), [ARM Assembler Reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/index.html), [iOS App in ASM](https://github.com/richardjrossiii/iOSAppInAssembly) (FYI: mine).

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III thanks for your suggestion~~in fact,i still don't understand why r1 should be changed.As you see, objc_getClass only need one parameter which means r0 was passed,and then the result should be stored in r0.no matter in what ways can't I find the reason that the  r1 be changed..........so i will read the link you suggest.

Comment: Read the ABI docs, here's a direct link to the section pertaining to register preservation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARMv6FunctionCallingConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009021-SW4

But I strongly recommend fully reading through the documentation I linked fully if you are interested in using ASM on iOS.